# Picking cards at random

Tags: probability

I want to know if my reasoning is correct for following problem.

I have 5 cards, 2 are marked with an X. What is the probability of getting a "hit" with increasing numbers of guesses?

My solution is reasoned like this:

With 1 pick, I have a 2 in 5 chance of picking a marked card. So 40% chance.

For 2 picks, it's as above plus (prob. I didn't pick it yet) * prob. to pick one = 2/5 + (1-2/5)*2/4 = 70%

For 3 picks, by extension of above argument = 7/10 + 3/10 * 2/3 = 90%

Extending to last case of a 4th pick which must get one of them, it's 9/10 + 1/10 * 2/2 = 100%

Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct, assuming you can't pick the same card twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  A way of checking your answer is by subtracting the chance of "miss" from 100%.
$$1-\frac{3}{5}=\frac{2}{5}\\1-\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{2}{4}=\frac{7}{10}\\1-\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{9}{10}\\1-\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}\times0=1\\$$

But your way of solving it is solid.

Comment: Ah excellent. I was wondering how to get there directly without having to calculate all the previous steps.